# Why won't my Hugo site display when deploying to Netlify?

Tags: hugo, netlify, toml

Locally, I can view my site easily and all theme changes.

However, once the site is deployed to Netlify, all I am greeted with is a blank white screen.

I tried toggling `baseURL` configurations to no avail. However, if I rename my `_index.md` file to `index.md` in the `/content` folder the contents of that file will display when deployed via Netlify.

There are no build errors in Netlify or locally.

My working files can be seen at the following [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Courtny/hugo-cotten).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanation Summary:** The `_index.md` file at the root of your content directory is using your `themes/gwynn/layouts/index.html` template, but you are not telling it to display any content or data from your frontmatter.

`themes/gwynn/layouts/index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  {{ range first 10 .Data.Pages }}
    <h1><a href={{ .Permalink }}>{{ .Title }}</a></h1>
  {{ end }}
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing is showing up because you are displaying only the pages in your site, but both have `draft: true` set in the frontmatter of the pages in post.

**Solution to show Home page Title:**

`themes/gwynn/layouts/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ .Title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ .Title }}</h1>
    {{ range first 10 .Data.Pages }}
      <h1><a href={{ .Permalink }}>{{ .Title }}</a></h1>
    {{ end }}
  </body>
</html>
```

To show the page links, you can set `draft: false` within `content/post/first.md` and `content/post/second.md`

Comment: Wow, thank you! I am embarrassed I overlooked such a simple piece of metadata! Is there a reason why my local instance is showing the draft states? Is there a way to tell it to show me a non-draft preview locally before deploying?

Comment: `hugo` builds the default for [Draft, Future, and Expired Content](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/usage/#draft-future-and-expired-content) `hugo server --buildDrafts` will show you the draft preview on a local server and `hugo server` without drafts.

Answer (score 1):

Netlify doesn’t automatically know that you have a Hugo site. In the app.netlify.com interface, navigate to Site settings, then “Build & deploy” in the left-hand navigation.

[image: netlify]

In the Build command field, type `hugo`, and in the Publish directory, type `public`. I *think* this should be enough.

(If not, here’s a [more detailed config](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-netlify/) from the Hugo site. That strikes me as too complicated, though.)

Going further, and this is optional, I prefer to run the `hugo` command locally, which generates the whole site, and the resulting `public` directory becomes part of my repo. In that case, I leave the above `Build command:` field blank, but keep the `Publish directory: public` field.